Glance widget lottie
I am wondering how to implement lottie file on glance widget, using json lottie from raw folder. How can I do this?
I checked the Glance widget documentation and tried do this the same as in a normal Activity, which did not work.

You can't.
Glance widgets are still subject to the same limitations as any other app widget:

Glance provides a modern approach to build app widgets using Compose, but is restricted by the limitations of AppWidgets and RemoteViews.

One of those restrictions is that you can't use custom Drawables, such as the LottieDrawable that Lottie provides, because your app is not handling the drawing:

You can only use drawable resources or bitmaps, not a Drawable object.
While your app has Lottie, your app is not rendering the app widget. The home screen renders the app widget.

Anything that relies on code within your app running at draw time is not possible.  Glance (and other means of creating RemoteViews) provides a declarative description of a UI structure, allowing the home screen to render it without needing to have every app with a widget running at draw time.
